# powershellv2 - add new parameter to custom object

Tags: object, powershell-2.0

I have created a custom Object using the code below, but I now need to add an additional property.

Reading the online documentation and help files suggests that I need to use `add-member` (as per my example below).
But When I run this I get:

```
Add-Member : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'newvar'.
```

What is the correct syntax to add a new parameter to an Object.

Also, if I wanted to update a parameter with a different value, can I use the the same add-member? (there doesn't appear to be an 'update-member' cmdlet)

```
$TestList = @(
"item1"
"item2"
)

$TESTObject = @()
foreach($a in $TestList)
    {
        $dItem = $a

        $TESTObject += New-Object PSObject -property @{
                item = "$dItem";
            }
    }

FOREACH($a in $TESTObject)
{   
    #DO STUFF HERE

    $newVar = 1234

    $a | Add-Member newvar $newVar   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I have found to do this is:

Add a member to a custom (`PSObject`) Object

```
Add-Member -InputObject $TESTObject -MemberType NoteProperty -Name newVar -Value $newVar
```

And to update an existing member I use

```
Add-Member -InputObject $TESTObject -MemberType NoteProperty -Name newVar -Value $newVar -force
```

whether this is the best way to do this (or even the correct way) I'm not sure. But it seems to work.